# Spring batch writer append data from next to next line

Tags: spring, spring-batch, filewriter

I am reading the data from DB and writing it to a plain text file using Spring batch. If I get 5 matching records, I am expecting to create a file with data in 5 lines. I am able to generate the file and everything works good except for the fact that each line is separated with a blank line in between.
For example:
I am expecting the records to created as-

1005 name1                lastname1               2017
1006 name2                lastname2               2017
1007 name3                lastname3               2017

But in actual file is getting created as-

1005 name1                lastname1               2017

1006 name2                lastname2               2017

1007 name3                lastname3               2017

I am not sure why the extra line in between is coming up. Could anyone please help me resolve it?

I am using below writer configuration:

```
<bean id="flatFileItemWriter" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:{fileLocation}"/>
        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator"/>
        </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: Did you verify if you are adding a new line character after constructing each line in your Item Reader?

Comment: No I am not adding a new line character. I am using default line separator given by FlatFileItemWriter class.

Comment: If I override line separator as "\n\r" it works for me but it also appends these characters which I do not want. Also, using "&#13;&#10;" didn't work either.

Comment: I believe issue is in the Item Reader. How do you convert the DB reads into output? Can you post that info?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<property name="lineSeparator" value="&#13;" />` to the Writer.

Also check to be sure your lines don'd have any line separator chars.